# how to make a search engine with nutch and cassandra?

Tags: solr, indexing, cassandra, search-engine, nutch

I am tring to implement a website search engine with java as an applet,I have used nutch as web crawler and cassandra as my database,I have to use a nosql database(because my teacher wants me to do),now my question is what should I do next to complete my search engine?

I have googled a lot,but all of the sites are mostly about nutch and solr,and they build search engines with integration of these two,cause solr itself is somehow a database,I don't know what should I do,do I have to use solr too to complete my search engine?is it wise to use two databases(solr and cassandra)?or I should do some thing else?

please remember I have to use cassandra.
and please first explain me if I have understood things in a wrong way and then give me a minus mark,:D

I will be really really thankfull for your help,I have got somehow confused.

by the way does solr counted as a nosql database?excuse me,I am new to them all.

Comment: why nobody answers me?

Comment: I don't want you to give a complete answer,I just want a clue,just like the thing Allan Macmillan did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Solr's Data Import Handler and see if you feel it would work.  It allows you to query your database and store the results with Solr to which then Solr can manipulate the reuslts.  Nutch also has very good integration with Solr should you choose to use it.

Comment: can that be named "developing or writing a search engine in java"?or it is just joining tools to each other in order to make a search engine?